# Sony Reader PRS-T1 becomes unresponsive

Tags: 2.2-froyo, performance, malware

My Sony Reader PRS-T1 based on Android 2.2 is acting funny.

I had rooted it in the past but is now in the "original" state, upgraded with the latest official firmware.

The problem is that many times, the unit becomes unresponsive. This happens after putting the unit on sleep and waking it again. The dictionary hangs, changing dictionaries hangs even worse and sometimes highlighting text as well (this makes the dictionary pop up.

I managed to get logs and I found the following error messages, just after waking from sleepmode:

```
2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 W dalvikvm (2308:2308) [log_main    ] ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier;.getProductName ()Ljava/lang/String;

2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 W dalvikvm (2308:2308) [log_main    ] ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier;.getSkuName ()Ljava/lang/String;

2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 W dalvikvm (2308:2308) [log_main    ] ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier;.getSerialNumber ()Ljava/lang/String;

2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 W dalvikvm (2308:2308) [log_main    ] ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier;.getServiceId ()Ljava/lang/String;

2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 W dalvikvm (2308:2308) [log_main    ] ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier;.getMacAddress ()Ljava/lang/String;

2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 W dalvikvm (2308:2308) [log_main    ] ERROR: Unable to find decl for native Lcom/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier;.getPsn ()Ljava/lang/String;

2013-01-22 17:15:06.391 E JNIHelp (2308:2308) [log_main    ] RegisterNatives failed for 'com/sony/drbd/ebook/system/Identifier'
```

Any ideas on how to diagnose and restore my system?

Comment: Maybe you'll take a look at [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/)

Comment: I already did a factory reset to no avail.

Comment: In that case, "malware" could only be in the system area (which is unlikely, though not impossible) or in one of the apps you explicitly installed yourself. Or it is rather a different performance issue (which I think is more likely). I'll re-tag your question; maybe you want to follow the performance related tag for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that backing up, reformatting the internal drive and restoring the backup.

After doing that, I also copied the internal partitions from another Reader and the problem is solved.

I suspect that it is the formatting which solved the problem but am not sure.

Procedure in this [forum post](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showpost.php?p=2408206&postcount=72).