# Apps force close on a Galaxy Ace GT-S5830i

Tags: samsung-galaxy-ace, force-close

Every app I use needs to be forced closed after less than 5 minutes. Even apps I haven't even opened [before]. I've turned off my phone and restarted it multiple times and nothing seems to work. Does this mean I have to do a factory reset?

Comment: Handset rooted?

Comment: Also worth checking: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575)

Comment: Yes, in this case, factory reset should be wise decision to make. Just don't forget to make a backup of your files before you do so.

Answer (score 6):

• First is make very sure you've free space of memory. My One Plus handset makes this behaviour when it is near to 'out of storage'.

• Second is make sure you have not deleted any root directory by opening file manager with some specific app explorer. (This might create problem as once i meshed up with those folders and end up tolerating crashes.)

• Third is the last option do a [factory reset](https://www.wikihow.com/Reset-a-Samsung-Galaxy-Ace) .

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a file permissions issue on the data directory.

The only fix would be to wipe, however if rooted and/or have a custom recovery, you should first try the fix permissions option.

Otherwise, you will have to do a factory reset.