# What should I do before I try advanced troubleshooting

Tags: troubleshooting, maintenance

Are there any generic troubleshooting steps and tips to be followed *before* I search for problem specific troubleshooting options? Then what are they?

I only have a general knowledge on Android and not familiar with flashing, shell commands, etc.

Comment: See also: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several steps/things you can do before you do advanced troubleshooting. Most of the problems can be solved following these steps.

1. **Backup your data.** Backup your data first (of course, if possible). You don't need to risk it. Keep it somewhere else. It is better to have backups for personal data and app data separately.
2. **Try rebooting your device.** You can use your power key or a third party [reboot app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dread7us.reboot.scheduler&hl=en)
3. **Keep your device switched off for a while.** Make sure you remove your SIM card (and the battery and SD card as well, if they are detachable) and wait about 30 minutes.
4. **Try freeing some space.** You *must* always have some free space. It is better to have more than 50MB free so that the apps can work smoothly. (Some say it should be 2% of total memory)
5. **Try re-installing apps.** If you believe your problem is caused by a specific app, try uninstalling and re-installing that app. Also you can try clearing the app cache. It will give you some *more* space.
6. **No hardware fixes.** Do not attempt to quick hardware fixes unless you have *clear understanding* of what you're doing. And keep in mind that you'll lose your manufacturer's warranty by doing such fixes.
7. **Update your OS.** Make sure that the relevant updates are compatible with your device, referring to your manufacturer's website.

If you are still in the problem, you can try searching help for your problem or contacting your manufacturer's customer support personnel. **Remember to do this before you go to *factory resets*.**

Comment: Sid, you may want to add: clean caches of misbehaving apps (as a *separate item* -- yes, I saw you have it in the "re-installing apps" section). This solved many app-specific problems in the past (especially Playstore). Insert before "freeing some space", and that then becomes "freeing some *more* space" :) Also: last resort = "factory reset" (needs backup before) might be a valid point here. Moreover, I would move "update your OS" 1 further to the end.

Comment: I have added that *last resort* before hand. Good thoughts by the way. :)

Comment: Travis Bemrose has [a question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/67853/what-does-leaving-your-device-off-for-a-while-do) regarding this post.  It would be good if you could please answer the question there, not here, so that we can preserve the comments which are there.