# What does leaving your device off for a while do?

Tags: troubleshooting, maintenance

This page: [What should I do before I try advanced troubleshooting](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36466/what-should-i-do-before-i-try-advanced-troubleshooting) says

3) **Keep your device switched off for a while.** Make sure you remove your SIM card (and the battery and SD card as well, if they are detachable) and wait about 30 minutes.

What is the purpose of that?  What is it expected to accomplish?

Comment: Have you switched off your computer for a while? The point am making is to ensure 1) memory will not hold residue after a period of time and 2) in context of smartphone/devices, to de-register the sim card from the network as in not actively scanning...

Comment: 1) What do you mean "memory will not hold residue".  A simple reboot clears all the RAM and starts fresh. 2) Is all that necessary to "de-register" the sim from the network? If the device is off, it doesn't remain in contact with the network right?  I can see that someone might recommend this step in an attempt to do that, but it seems to be more than is necessary.  It almost sounds like an attempt to separate and air cool the components.

Comment: for 1) static discharge. What is your point of asking the question - you have troubleshooted a PC?... same thing applies.

Comment: @t0mm13b The point of asking the question, is that the answer on that page had a strange recommendation with no explanation as to why.  No, I've never attempted to discharge static from a computer by leaving it off/open/out for a period of time.  Doing so could actually increase static charge (depending on the conditions of the environment).  When working on a computer I've always discharged the static by 1) grounding the power leads, 2) grounding the case.  Takes a couple seconds and done.  I don't understand the intent of leaving a phone in this state for this length of time.

Comment: The question is too broad in that there is no right or wrong answer and is subjective, to each and to their own opinions.

Comment: @t0mm13b I would have left a comment on the answer, tagging Sid and waiting for him to speak for himself, but the site won't let me do that.  The reputation based privileges can be so frustrating.  Asking a question here was my only option.

Comment: @t0mm13b I've been a constructive member of StackExchange for 2 years, but I don't spend all my time here so I only have 283 rep spread out over 8 sites. I can usually find help without asking duplicate questions.  I really wish all the different sites weren't so schizophrenic with their rep and allowed me to ask a clarifying comment, or let me reward others by voting up on a question or answer I found useful.  Do you have a better way for me to contact Sid for clarification?  Maybe you could tag him on a comment on that answer, with a link here. It's not great, but what else is there?

Comment: I, too, suspect that Sid is advising you to separate and air-cool your phone's components.  Removing and later reinserting the SIM and SD cards will also help to ensure that they're inserted correctly.