# Nexus 7 Incredibly Slow

Tags: nexus-7, 4.2-jelly-bean, performance

Over the past few weeks, my Nexus 7 running 4.2 Jelly Bean has gotten incredibly slow at times. Sometimes I can count off a full five (or more) seconds for an app to open or even for something as simple as scrolling from one home screen to another. I've had the device for three or four months and it just recently started giving me problems. I hadn't installed anything new prior to noticing the problem and everything that I have installed came from the Play store, so it should all be safe. Rebooting the device does not seem to help.

What can I do to diagnose and hopefully fix this problem? This is my first Android device so I don't even really know where to start.

Comment: Maybe you take a look at [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575), which has a few things to consider and might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed the same issue on my Nexus 7 running stock Jelly Bean 4.2. I also noticed reboots. Do you happen to have HD Widgets installed? That seemed to be the cause of many of my slow downs, but unfortunately not all. Apps that use location services seem to be the issue with my slowdowns. Are you noticing the same thing?

This [article](http://blogs.computerworld.com/android/21427/android-42-random-reboots) goes into some of the issues seen on 4.2 that I experienced.

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot, reboot to safe mode by long pressing the Power Off on the power-off menu.

Screenshot from my N4:

[image: http://goo.gl/8FZD7]

Comment: Ugh. Please don't use URL shorteners.

Comment: How do I determine which app is causing the problem once I'm in safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some of your app is eating your CPU :

- One (extrem) solution would be to do a complete [factory reset](http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2668187), and then reinstall the app you need.
- You could check your CPU usage (there are many apps for that : [Android System Info](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi), [CPU Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pocketappbuilders.cpuusagestatusbar)...), who, how long... and find who is too greedy

Answer (score 1):

If your available space gets too low, the Nexus 7 will become laggy.

Go to Settings->Storage and check the number next to Available.  If it's under 3gb, try moving some data off the device (movies, music, etc.) via USB to get the available space to 3gb or more.

If this corrects the performance problem, then you can restore data a bit at a time to fine tune the threshold where performance drops off.

I don't know of a hard and fast rule for how much free space should be available.

FWIW: My Nexus 7 became very laggy (long pauses for the keyboard to pop up after entering a text field, switching tabs in Chrome was very slow) and I tried uninstalling apps, disabling apps that ran as services to no avail.  I checked my free space and it was 750mb.  I deleted a movie I had copied to the device and freed up an additional 2gb.  As soon as I did that, the lag vanished.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Nexus 7 2013 has a hardware problem in bad SSD that is dying quite fast. Newest Android helped with this as it was writing to disc more data, so Nexus 7 devices started dying faster. I don't know if this is problem of all 2013 Nexus 7 devices or just the first batch, but mine is unusable now and I just trashed it today.

There are some "workarounds" floating around to enforce TRIM, but this does not really help much (for some time yes, there are technical reasons for that).

More info: http://www.geek.com/android/the-nexus-7-lag-dilemma-and-why-theres-no-real-fix-1560784/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is better explained [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/01/21/having-lag-issues-on-your-newish-device-new-app-lagfix-aims-to-make-it-perform-like-new-again/), it seems to happen when your device is almost full. If you are rooted then you can check the [lagfix app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grilledmonkey.lagfix), it did make a difference on my Nexus.

Comment: We want answers on Stack Exchange to be self-contained. There is no useful information here; it's all behind that link. Worse, when that link stops functioning, this answer is absolutely worthless.