# Samsung Galaxy S has become very slow

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, performance

My phone recently has begun to become very slow. At certain times of the day, the phone will completely stop working and will have to be turned off by holding the power button. Sometimes, the lock screen will also cause problems.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: have you installed a software or app

Comment: some apps have very resource intensive background processes

Comment: There are any number of apps (or even built-in tools) that can help you figure out what's eating up your CPU cycles. Have you tried any of them?

Comment: how do i check which is taking the most CPU power?

Comment: Maybe related: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575)