# Cannot open message application on Samsung Galaxy S2 and Deleted all of my Contacts

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, contacts, sms, data-recovery

I was originally getting an error message about the logserver not working, which I fixed through managing the application and forcing it to close, but now I get another error when I try to access text messages:

> The application messaging has stopped unexpectedly.
>
> [Force Close]

Then it doesn't let me access messages. When I cleared the data from my contacts like someone advised, I deleted all of my contacts, and messaging still doesn't work! There was not an option to clear the cache data, and when I try to sync my contacts to my phone from Facebook and my Google account, NOTHING happens.

I need to get my contacts back somehow and figure out how to get the messaging app working. I have tried to look up solutions but I don't understand what most people are saying and I am so frustrated. I do not understand what it means to be "rooted", although I did install the app ES File Explorer which seems to have done nothing.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: *ES File Explorer* is a very good file manager, but does nothing on its own. "root" is the Administrator account, which by default is not available on Android devices; if you root your device, you get full access to the system (but might void your warranty). As to your force-close problem, you might want to take a look at [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575). Concerning your contacts: Can you still see them in GMail via its website?

Answer (score -3):

The only way that I have tried is to download GO SMS Pro and delete the longest message.