# Do you need to run uninstallers/cleaners on Android to maintain performance levels like on Windows?

Tags: uninstallation, maintenance

You'll have to forgive me as I'm not as familiar with the internal workings of Android/Linux as I am with Windows.

I'm curious about performance degrading on an Android device in the absence of, for lack of a better term, maintenance. When I try out a bunch of apps and then uninstall them, do I need to run any sort of cleanup? I know Android doesn't have a registry like Windows but does it have some part of the operating system that gets cluttered up and needs to be tended to/purged over time?

Comment: Usually not: as you already said, there's no "registry" or the like. Only when you experience problems, there might be some cleanup needed. You might want to check [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575) for related information.

Answer (score 3):

As for uninstalling apps, I don't think so.  Standard apps (ones that don't use root access) have at most three parts:

### A single executable file

- A `.apk` archive containing the entire app -- similar to Windows apps that are entirely contained in a `.exe` file (like most installers: It not only carries all the code it needs but also all pictures, config files it needs, etc.)
- It is stored in `/data/app` usually

### A single folder containing all userdata

- This is for things like settings storage, or caches
- Although this is comparable to yoir `appdata` folder it doesn't get cluttered because apps are only allowed a single folder here that is managed completely by the system and is easily deleted when uninstalled
- Stored in `/data/data`

### Possibly another folder in `/sdcard/Android/data`

- Basically the same as the `/data/data` folder but if the app needs a lot of space for extra files it puts them here

When an app is uninstalled, all these parts are destroyed by the system, so I can't think of anything that would get cluttered but the fragmentation of the sdcard.  <strike>**DO NOT** download any defrag apps (I haven't found a single one that wasn't some sort of scam).  Instead, get a card reader and defrag it on your PC if need be.</strike>

**Edit**: As suggested by Izzy below, [SD Maid](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) is a nice manager/cleaner

Comment: Hoho... A non-scam app would be [SD Maid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm). But you are right: In general, things work like you described. "Left-overs" are rather exceptions. But still, they *sometimes* happen...

Comment: There's no point defragging an SD card - you'll just shorten its life.  Android isn't Windows - don't treat it as such.

Comment: @PoldieMar defragmentation doesn't slow anything down?

Comment: @Poldie Also, isn't defragging strictly an NTFS thing? Or does it also apply to FAT32?

Comment: @Poldie *fragmentation

Comment: Files can get fragmented on any file system which allows large files to be spread across several physical locations on the disk. The point is, this can slow down hard drives because the heads have to physically move to each location to read the data, whereas solid state storage can just access any area of memory with next to no latency.