# Some apps closing, crashing, some not starting, flashing

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, internal-storage, app2sd, task-management, insufficient-memory

I can very well see in the *Settings > Applications > Manage Applications* screen that internal memory (ummm I think thats the ROM) of my phone is almost filled up. Although I can see in Running Services screen that more than 150MB of RAM is still free.

My device started giving this behavior.

- some apps crash automatically
- Some apps does not start at all. When I click on them they simply simply flash the screen
- Some games after loading and showing the menu and main screen animation, when I click on Play or Start new game, it does not do anything

Now I stuck with this ROM fill up. I have moved all apps that I can move to SD card through [AppMgr Pro III (App 2 SD)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd.pro&hl=en). But still many apps have some footprints in internal memory (or ROM??) since I can still see them in the *Manage Applications* screen. Why is it so? What could be the other way out, apart from uninstalling unused apps.

Comment: Maybe [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/16575) proves helpful to you?

Comment: In addition to what @Izzy said, you can try doing "fix permissions" in ClockworkMod recovery, assuming you have it installed.