# RAM usage per app on Android?

Tags: ram

Is there a way to tell the RAM usage per app on Android?
That's a basic feature on all Linux distros but I haven't been able to find that for Android. Only the total usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android system RAM usage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42405/android-system-ram-usage)

Comment: You can try [WhatsRunning](https://github.com/mirfatif/WhatsRunning). Disclosure: I'm the author of the app.