# Galaxy Note 1 has become slow after upgrading the phone 4.1.2

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-note

My Phone (Samsung Galaxy Note) has become really slow after I have upgraded my phone with 4.1.2. And I don't have any much data in my phone. I am really unhappy with this update. Can we do something about it?

Comment: You could check if some of the steps here prove helpful: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)

Comment: I have the same problem after upgrading. Clearing caches didn't help. I will be downgrading the OS. Look elsewhere on this site on how to downgrade.

Comment: See my solution on this question. Perhaps it helps. http://android.stackexchange.com/a/45332/8649