# Phone becomes slow after updating to Jelly Bean

Tags: performance, samsung-galaxy-note

My Samsung Galaxy Note-1 becomes very slow after updating it to Jelly bean...what should I do???
Please can any body help me??

Comment: Have you done factory reset after update?

Comment: Maybe you find some more help here: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575) -- though that one is not directly related to an update.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution from [another website](http://droidviews.com/2012/how-to-recover-when-your-android-device-is-caught-in-bootloop/):

Method 1:
If your device is on stock firmware, that also means it does not have a custom recovery like CWM or TWRP not installed on it, do the following steps:

Pull out the the battery of your phone, wait for about 30 seconds and reinsert it to its place.
Boot your device into ASR (Android System Recovery) mode. The method involves a hardware key combination and varies from one phone to another. For Samsung phones, for example, the key combination is Volume Up+ Home + Power keys. The tablets which generally have no Home button, you can enter the Recovery mode by pressing and holding the Volume Up + Power keys simultaneously.
In the Android System Recovery, scroll down to “wipe data/factory reset” option using the volume rockers and select it using the power key.
In case, wiping the data factory does not help you, you should also try “wipe cache partition”.
When you have wiped the data/factory, go back to the main menu and reboot the device by “reboot system now” option.
The bootloop problem should be fixed now.

Method 2:
If  you have a rooted device with CWM Recovery installed and your phone is caught into a bootloop after flashing a custom ROM or mod, do as follows:

Pull out the battery, reinsert it after 30 seconds and boot the device into CWM Recovery: Volume Up+ Home + Power keys simultaneously.
Go to “Advanced”
Choose “Wipe dalvik-cache”
Now go to “Mounts & Storage”
Choose “Wipe /cache”
Reboot your phone
The bootloop should be gone now. If it still persists, do this.

Boot the phone again into CWM Recovery
Now go to “Mounts & Storage”
Choose “Wipe /data”
Choose “Wipe /cache”
Then reboot your phone.
Now the phone should reboot normally. Next time when you install a ROM, follow the instructions prescribed by the developer. Be more attentive to the warnings before experimenting with any third party ROM or mod. Always ensure what you are about to install is meant for your device.

If the Above Methods Do Not Work!
In case you are not able to get your device come out of bootloop, your final option should be to install or restore a previously backed up ROM by putting the device in recovery mode, or to install the official firmware/factory image to your phone your tablet.

Comment: Anyway method 1 did the trick for me.