# Do Android devices become slower with time?

Tags: performance

I own a Galaxy S (2.3.5 / GT-I9000 / BVJV3) and use it since two and a half years. I also have bought more recent hardware, like an iPad Mini and a more recent Android tablet, which comparatively are much more reactive.

So I was wondering if the slowness of my device was just a feeling, or if devices actually become less responsive with time ? The phone is always lagging (click sounds always a second behind), running the basic functions of the phone (messages, phone, contacts) always need a good 4 seconds to actually show on screen, returning to the home screen sometimes takes 5 to 10 seconds while it's doing something to the icons. A game like Pudding Monsters is bacically unplayable, but I didn't expect this phone to run recent games.

Comment: Have you tried doing a factory restore? Was it like this when you bought it?

Comment: I would say yes. I know for instance that my Windows computers become slower with time. This is because I am using them every day. I install and uninstall applications, most of them leave shitty data behind, some of them manage to screw up and bloat the registry, and it all just adds up. Even when not installing too many applications, just by using them data is generated. Therefore I try to keep it a policy to reinstall Windows (or any other OS) at least two times a year. Now-days Windows and applications for Windows have become more efficient and effective though.

Comment: I didn't want to evoke Windows because I haven't used it for a very long time (before XP) , but this was a recurring problem at that time (the slow bloating of the system that invariably ended by "formatting the computer") that looks similar to what I'm witnessing.

Comment: Yeah, it's like that Daft Punk song, Technologic. "Name it, rate it, tune it, print it, Scan it, send it, fax - rename it, Touch it, bring it, pay it, watch it, Turn it, leave it, start - format it." It's all part of a technological life cycle. So I suggest you "format it". I'm sure it wasn't like that when you first bought it?..

Comment: You might want to take a look into [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)