# Samsung Galaxy S3 suddenly crashing everyday

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Samsung Galaxy S3 
GT-I9300
Android 4.1.2
Baseband I9300XELK1
Kernel Version 3.0.31-764725
Build Number JZO54K.I9300XXELCC

NOT rooted

For the past couple of weeks this device has suddenly started to crash at least once a day

1. While using an app it would freeze
2. After no usage for some time, phone would go on standby and will refuse to wake up.
3. Sometimes it would reboot by itself

Have to hold down power button and restart the device. What should I do? Thank you

Comment: What type of apps that cause it to freeze?

Comment: Can't tell. Any app could cause it. I'm on stock browser and Flipboard the most so those are where I see it happen the most. But I've encountered it when using Facebook, etc @Jack

Comment: Have you checked with [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)