# HTC One V really slow

Tags: performance, htc-one-v

I bought my HTC One V exactly one year ago, at first everything went really smoothly and it worked like a charm.

It didn't take long before the phone crashed from an `unexpected error`. The phone spent most of the time in my pocket then, I would notice it because it vibrates then or the next time there would be that error-sign in the upper left corner.

I started living with the fact it sometimes shut itself down, but now the messaging app is beginning to lag:

When I want to send a message (or make a call), it happens that I cannot see my contacts. (which are imported from Google) But it could also be that I have to wait a minute or more because the messages for that contact are loading.

How can I fix these problems with my phone?

My Android version is 4.0.3

Comment: May be too many messages or too many contacts?

Comment: last week i set it up to limit it to 50 messages/conversation and 196 contacts isn't that much, i guess

Comment: Ya. That definitely is not much. So that never is the problem then.

Comment: You might want to check [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575). Please report back if that solves your issue, or otherwise what you've tried and were you're stuck.

Comment: I already cleared my applications cache two days ago, didn't solve much. If i remember well i did a factory reset 3 times too

Comment: Bad SD card can be the cause sometime.

Comment: Or bad (cache) files on the SD card that weren't removed by the factory reset.