# Android on Samsung Galaxy Duos is too slow

Tags: performance, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

I've bought a Samsung Galaxy Duos GT-S7562 with Android 4.0.4 3 months ago. The phone is so slow and getting slower by the ay, it has become almost useless. For instance, to look up and call a contact can take more than a minute. Some apps simply won't start, nor work and prefer crashing. I can literally count to 3 between the moment I click to take a picture and the moment the camera will actually take the picture.

I haven't found a solution to this on Internet so far. The only thing I can think of is tossing the phone on a wall, but somehow I think that won't help.

How can I make my phone be worth the 200$ I paid for again?

Comment: Have you considered a factory reset?

Comment: Yes, but it was slow very early already. If I will reset, I will have to reconfigure my phone and what difference will that theoretically make?

Comment: A point to check would be [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575). But if it was slow to begin with, it's rather something for the Samsung support team.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't overcome hardware issues.