# Improving HTC Sensation XE somehow

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, performance, htc-sensation-xe

I have an HTC Sensation XE and the smartphone is becoming slower and worse every day, expecially compared to my Nexus 7 and Samsung Tab 2.

Android on the phone is slow and lagged ( I have to wait even 6-7 second after clicking somewhere), the battery depletes very fast and the phone itself becomes very hot if I do something "intensive" like using google maps.
the Android version on the phone is 4.0.3 and as far as I know, there is no update.

What can I do to improve the phone? It's market value makes it not worth to sell and it is still working, so I would like to find a way to fix it somehow, what can i do?
I like a lot the vanilla Android of the Nexus 7, there is any way that I can put a plain android on the HTC, keeping all the functionalities? I dont care of Htc Sense, but I want to be able to use the camera, 3g, wifi, GPS and so on.

Maybe some kind of reset would be enough to bring it bask to it's best days?

Comment: Have you checked with our [performance tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/performance/info) for some first aid? Especially interesting in your case might be: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)

Comment: I didn't know about those pages, I will check them carefully, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If any of them solves your issue, don't forget to let us know ;)

Comment: Any progress made so far? Maybe you even could answer your own question meanwhile? ;)

Comment: I've taken out most of the apps and the performance is slightly improved, but it is still too slow. I will wipe it out ad a last resort and then check if there is any improvement on the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a system wipe and reinstall. This significantly sped up my Sensation.

Comment: I've done it and it's like new now!