# what is latest android version for samsung s7562?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos

i want to know which is the latest android version for samsung galaxy s duos s7562. in my phone android 4.0.3 is installed but it is very slow.though not much applications installed still it takes 8-10 seconds to respond to touch commands

Comment: A newer Android version won't make your device faster necessarily. You might instead want to take a look at [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)

Answer (score 0):

4.0.4 is currently the latest version, and updating your device does not make it any faster. 
Try formatting your device as S Duos is prone to lag after some use.