# Samsung Note 2 slow down

Tags: performance, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I find my note 2 is getting slower and slower after using it for 1 year. Is there anything I can do to make my phone run normally/faster. It looks like the memory is approaching to the max usage. Is there any way to keep the memory at a lower level?

Comment: Memory usage in sense ram or the storage?

Comment: regarding to the ram，not storage.

Comment: is your phone rooted?

Comment: You can try restarting your phone regularly

Comment: Have you seen [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)

Comment: it is not root. any suggestion？

Comment: i have tried restarting but it seems not working out.

Answer (score -1):

The speed of your device relates to the RAM not ROM. RAM of NOTE2 is 2GB and RAM is not expandable. RAM is the memory where all your foreground and background process resides. If RAM usage in your device is very high, uninstall or disable unnecessary applications. And install a Task Killer and schedule it in crazy mode at every half hour. It may increase the speed of your system.

You can manually clear your ram from task manager. Long press home button then tap on left most option which is task manager there select ram tab and tap on clear Memory.

If you have root access you can use autorun manager to permanently disable unnecessary background processes from startup.

Comment: -1 for recommending task killers, which do more harm than good.