# OnePlus Two Freezes often

Tags: performance, oneplus-two

I have been using the OnePlus Two for few months now. About two months ago it started freezing and slowing down. Often I have to power cycle the phone in order to get it working again. Usually it happens when I charge the phone, listen to music, or watch videos.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Any ideas how to find why its being so slow, and how to fix it?

Comment: Related: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575) Also see our [performance tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/performance/info).

Comment: I did clear the cache on all the apps, i removed a whole bunch of apps as well. It seemed to work at first, but then it started all over again. The phone is not rooted, not modified in any way.