# fstrim not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, root-access, performance, samsung-galaxy-note-2, lagging

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note II running CyanogenMod 11, so it's obviously rooted.  As of recently the phone seems very laggy and much slower than it used to be.  So I did some research and tried `fstrim`, [among other things](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35367/my-device-is-getting-slow-apps-start-misbehaving-crashing-what-can-i-do/35368#35368).

However, when I run `fstrim -v /data` as root (I use terminal emulator), `fstrim` outputs:

```
/data: 505982976 bytes trimmed
```

However, when I repeat the above command, I get exactly the same output.  In my eyes this indicates the trim does not work and the system remains slow.  I do the same on my Linux desktop machine and subsequent `fstrim -v` commands output zero bytes trims, to me this is what I expect on Android as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to check if the fstrim binary in your device is not problematic, also try this app: **[FS Trimmer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fifthelement.trimmer)**..

Comment: @GokulNC I have tried FS Trimmer before, but it appears it's just using the `fstrim` available on the system.  Any idea how to update/check the `fstrim` binary available on the system?

Comment: Oops, I thought that app uses its own version of `fstrim`. Also try the fstrim provided by [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox); *maybe* that has the latest version. And if your device is F2FS formatted (instead of EXT3/4), then it'll automatically be trimmed by the kernel; no need of explicitly doing that (maynot work)

Comment: @GokulNC Thanks, but BusyBox did not fix the issue either.  It's formatted using ext4.  I think I might try a new rom and formatting to use f2fs... but that's for another day.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution ? I have the same problem with a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 8" (SM-T310) running LineageOS 14.1.
BusyBox 1.30.1 won't help either.